# Why do I receive only 64K data in socket communication between C and Java code?

Tags: java, c, sockets, tcp

I'm using socket as a bridge between a C program and a Java program. C side is the server socket and receives the data from the Java side to process the data and send back the result. Java side is the client socket and sends the data to C side for processing and then receives the result from C side.

**C side code (server):**

```
const int SOCKET_BUF_IN_LEN = 160024;    //socket_buf_in length
const int SOCKET_BUF_OUT_LEN = 5000;     //socket_buf_out length

unsigned char socket_buf_in[SOCKET_BUF_IN_LEN];
unsigned char socket_buf_out[SOCKET_BUF_OUT_LEN];
struct AlgSocketIn alg_socket_in;
struct AlgSocketOut alg_socket_out;

//... some socket connection setup code 
setsockopt(new_socket_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVBUF, &SOCKET_BUF_IN_LEN, sizeof(SOCKET_BUF_IN_LEN));

bytes_recv = recv(new_socket_fd, socket_buf_in, SOCKET_BUF_IN_LEN, 0);

run_alg();    //process the data

bytes_send = send(new_socket_fd, socket_buf_out, SOCKET_BUF_OUT_LEN, 0);
```

The socket send buffer `socket_buf_in` has 160024 bytes as indicated above. I set the socket buffer to be this size by using `setsockopt()`.

**Java side code (client):**

```
public AlgOutData sendRecvData(AlgInData inData, int portNum) {
    AlgOutData outData = new AlgOutData();
    Socket sock = new Socket("localhost", portNum);
    int sentBytes, recvBytes;
    sock.setSendBufferSize(160024);
    sentBytes = serializeData(inData, sock);    //send data to server
    recvBytes = deserializeData(outData, sock); //receive result from server
    sock.close();
    return outData;
}

private int serializeData(AlgInData inData, Socket socket) throws IOException {
    int totalNumSamples = 160024;
    DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream(), 160024));
    for(int i=0; i<totalNumSamples; i++) {
        os.writeByte(inData.getSamples()[i]);
    }
    os.flush();
    int numBytes = os.size();
    return numBytes;
}
```

But when I started both the C program and Java program and upon finishing sending bytes from Java side to C side, I found that C side only received 65536 bytes from TCP socket stream. I debugged it and found this by looking at this line in C code:

```
bytes_recv = recv(new_socket_fd, socket_buf_in, SOCKET_BUF_IN_LEN, 0);
```

Upon finishing this call, `bytes_recv` is 65536 bytes, not 160024 bytes which is the length of the `socket_buf_in`.

However on Java side, I found that the data sent is indeed 160024 bytes. In `serializeData()`, the line shows

```
//....      
os.flush();
int numBytes = os.size();
```

`numBytes` is 160024 after the call to `os.flush()`.

So why do I only get 65536 bytes of data on C side while Java side sends all 160024 bytes data? Do I use the correct socket send/receive functions correctly on C side?

I also tried using the following code on C side to repeatedly receive byte stream until all 160024 bytes are received:

```
num_bytes = 0;
while (num_bytes < SOCKET_BUF_IN_LEN) {
    bytes_recv = recv(new_socket_fd, socket_buf_in, SOCKET_BUF_IN_LEN, 0);
    if (bytes_recv < 0)
        handle_error("Error on socket recv.\n");
    num_bytes += bytes_recv;
}
```

But this time, even though `num_bytes` is 160024, the socket buffer `socket_buf_in[160024]` has all zero values, which is wrong.

On the other hand, when I debugged the Java side code, I found that even though I set the output stream object `os` to have 160024 buffer size, it only writes bytes correctly up to 20024 bytes, not 160024 bytes.

What is wrong in either C side or Java side code for socket communication of 160024 bytes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You final loop looks almost correct, however you'll need to move the pointer passed into recv as you read data into the array.  Otherwise each call is overwriting the beginning of the array.  Something like

```
bytes_recv = recv(new_socket_fd, socket_buf_in+num_bytes, SOCKET_BUF_IN_LEN, 0);
```

Comment: This is the cause. I should have moved the pointer by num_bytes for each call. So why do I need to make successive calls to `recv()` in a loop to receive all 160024 bytes even though I specified the socket buffer to be of length 160024? Is it due to the TCP protocol?

Comment: There are various command in C that behave like this, they return the number of bytes read and leave it up to the programmer to keep calling the function until all the required data is delivered.  The main reason for this is that many of these commands (including recv) may not have all the data available at the time the function is called, so they return what they have instead of waiting.  Some commands may not even know how much data is going available.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation on this. I do see that every time `recv()` returns an indefinite number of bytes, not a fixed number.